# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I installed MySQL on Mac OS X Mountain Lion with `homebrew install mysql`, but when I tried `mysql -u root` I got the following error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Didn't post it as an answer but you have to `install mysql-server` package aswell, not just `mysql`

Comment: You're right, Hanky Panky, I found a script that fully installs all you need for MySQL on my system (Mac OSX Mountain Lion) and that did the trick. I must have been missing a couple of things.

Comment: @shrewdbeans what script did you find that fully installs all MySQL dependencies on mac??

Comment: @HankyPanky maybe that was true when you wrote it. But in 2016 Brew has no `mysql-server` to `install`.

Comment: It's important to note that you **installed using Homebrew** so ignore the non-homebrew tips and start (and restart on startup) with `brew services start mysql` or (if you don't want a background service) `mysql.server start`.

Comment: find if `mysql.sock` exists in first place with `sudo find / -type s | grep mysql`

Comment: @prayagupd and if it doesn't exist, what to do? Cause I didn't find mine after a mysql crash due to big database.

Comment: @KeitelDOG ["The socket file is created when the service is started and removed when the service is terminated."](https://serverfault.com/questions/279366/what-should-mysqld-sock-contain-why-dont-i-have-it) and is mentioned in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` in MacOS would be in different place in other Linux distros. It should be present if you start mysql service again

Comment: I got it to work but with old normal mysql `5.7.19`. The new mysql@5.7 version `5.7.24` couldn't work because the some config reference was kept linked to the old mysql instead of the new brew Cellar mysql@5.7 Keg. So thanks I try this later

Comment: This error is also likely to happen after running `brew upgrade` which will install a newer version of mysql than previously installed.

Comment: worked for me .
mysqld stop
then brew services start mysql

Comment: work - "brew services start mysql"

Comment: I'm getting the same problem in Monterey and have tried every single suggestion on this page, including completely wiping out MySQL and the databases and reinstalling. Still getting the error.

Comment: check your mysql directory location and give the permission
like
sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /-your-root-directories-/mysql
for my pc it is 
     sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
and then restart the mysql server
   sudo mysql.server start

Answer (score 150, accepted):

> It's probably because MySQL is installed but not yet running. [...] To verify that it's running, open up Activity Monitor and under "All Processes", search and verify you see the process "mysqld".

You can start it by installing "MySQL.prefPane".

The above quote is from the blog [Obscured Clarity, "Install MySQL on Mac OS X"](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.in/2009/08/install-mysql-on-mac-os-x.html), where you can also find the complete tutorial that I found most helpful.

Comment: I just ran `mysqld` and that was all, this was an issue caused by _poor shutting down_ due to a sort of _hard reset/shut-down_ of the system.

Comment: None of the suggested methods worked. For me, it was running, however, there was a permission issue. Running `sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql && sudo brew services restart mysql@5.7` solved the issue

Comment: When looking in Activity Monitor, the mysqlId is running; to work around this just stop mysql then restart it.

Comment: ✅ For me was `sudo chown -R your_user /usr/local/var/mysql/ && mysql.server start` after a hard reset

Comment: The brew service mysql@5.6 is running, and using `sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql && sudo brew services restart mysql@5.6` didn't fix the issue. Changing them back to my perms and restarting didn't either. I had previously uninstalled mysql@5.7 then installed mysql@5.6 and added the .zshrc alias for mysql. On to the next SO answer :/ yay Mac

Answer (score 233):

You'll need to start MySQL before you can use the `mysql` command on your terminal. To do this, run `brew services start mysql`. By default, brew installs the MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run: `mysql_secure_installation`.

To connect run: `mysql -uroot`. `root` is the username name here.

Comment: Running `sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql && sudo brew services restart mysql@5.7` solved the issue

Comment: For those wondering `mysql_secure_installation` is a mariaDB specific script.

Comment: `brew services start mysql` success. But when I run `mysql -uroot` after it, still the same error.

Comment: is it necessary to run this every time a Mac starts up or will running it once get rid of the error / keep MySQL running or start on startup?

Comment: Running this once should be enough.

Comment: `brew services stop mysql` for stopping the service, useful for newbies like me.

Answer (score 187):

This happened after the homebrew install and occurs due to permission issues. The following commands fixed the issue.

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql

sudo mysql.server start
```

Comment: you are awesome @nirojan, I was hitting my head to the wall :thumsup:

Comment: Cool. I can solve my problem when change to another mac admin account :)

Comment: Thanks a million. I've been cracking my head for more than 5 hours now. Seen multiple answers on the internet and only this helped.

Comment: Kudos! But when I restarted my MacBook, I have the same issue.

Comment: On my Mac, I had to `chown -R myuser /usr/local/var/mysql` (where myuser is my username). That immediately triggered a dialog asking if mysql was allowed to have incoming connections.

Comment: even if its not from brew the permission issues happens on many systems.

Comment: chown: /usr/local/var/mysql: No such file or directory

From brew install notes:
mysql@5.7 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

Comment: I'm getting this:
` ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/Saranshs-MacBook-Pro-2.local.pid).`
OS: Catalyna
mysql: 5.7.29

Comment: me too: Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/localhost.pid).

Comment: I got this error after run the commands `The server quit without updating PID file`

Comment: Did not fix here. I got `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/XXX-XXX-XXX.local.pid)`

Comment: Nothing on this page is working for me after doing a brew uninstall of mysql@5.7 then install mysql@5.6 even though I followed brew's instructions to the letter. The error started after I rebooted the Mac (Big Sur). Changing permissions and restarting the brew service doesn't help. Changing them back to my username and group doesn't either. I get the updating PID file error as well. I'm stumped. It appears it's trying to pull from /tmp when Big Sur doesn't work like that. I'm not sure where to update that.

Comment: It worked but I'm wondering why I need to do this now. Before I don't even need this.

Answer (score 51):

Run: `brew info mysql`

And follow the instructions. From the description in the formula:

```
Set up databases to run AS YOUR USER ACCOUNT with:
    unset TMPDIR
    mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp

To set up base tables in another folder, or use a different user to run
mysqld, view the help for mysql_install_db:
    mysql_install_db --help

and view the MySQL documentation:
  * http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db.html
  * http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html
```

Answer (score 42):

As others have pointed out this is because MySQL is installed but the service isn't running. There are many ways to start the MySQL service and what worked for me is the below.

To start the service:

1. Go to "System Preference"
2. At the bottom pane there should be MySql icon.
3. Double click that to launch the 'MySQL Server Status' and press the button 'Start MySQL Server'

*My env:*

*Mac Yosemite 10.10.3*

*Installed Package: /Volumes/mysql-advanced-5.6.24-osx10.8-x86_64*

Comment: @HosMercury can you confirm that you have MySQL installed

Comment: I download and install mysql from official Mysql web page. This solution works for me. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, i downloaded and installed mysql from official web page as well, but in the preference pane the server is not activated (red dot), when I click 'start sql server' it turns 'green' for a second and back to red, nothing happens. I tried 'chown' , symlink to tmp/mysql.socket, uninstall/re-install, brew install mysql, but all failed. the brew install gives me an unsatisfied error, something about requiring Sierra or higher OS. I am running el capitan. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 36):

Solutions revolve around:

- changing MySQL's permissions

  ```
  sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
  ```
- Starting a MySQL process

  ```
  sudo mysql.server start
  ```

Just to add on a lot of great and useful answers that have been provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450091/for-a-newbie-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-so) and from many different posts, **try specifying the host** if the above commands did not resolve this issue for you, i.e

```
mysql -u root -p h127.0.0.1
```

Comment: For me it was the permissions issue

Comment: it should be: mysql -u root -p -h127.0.0.1

Comment: Wow, such a better solution than wiping out all my local stuff.  This was a quick fix!

Comment: I tried above but eventually, this worked :

sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

Comment: Wow! I've tries dozens of commands and only this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 29):

The designated data directory /usr/local/var/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.

```js
MacOS:
$brew services stop mysql
$brew services list
$brew uninstall  mysql

$brew install mysql
$brew postinstall mysql

If Any error found then run those cmd
! Warning: this will delete any databases on this server:
$sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
$sudo rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
$brew postinstall mysql


$brew services start mysql
$mysql_secure_installation
```

[image]
Completed All process of secure installation then run

```
$mysql -u root -p
```

Congratulations you’ve just set up mysql!

Comment: I followed all of your steps and I still get the same error below
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: This should be the number 1 solution. Vote more for this.

Comment: Um yeah please don't just rm `/usr/local/var/mysql`, that's where your databases are stored and you'll lose them

Answer (score 20):

Looks like your mysql server is not started. I usually run the stop command and then start it again:

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

Same error, and this works for me.

Answer (score 20):

### Warning - this method will remove all of your databases in the `/usr/local/var/mysql` folder

I had MySQL installed with Homebrew, and the only thing that fixed this for me was re-installing MySQL.

On my company laptop, I didn't have permission to uninstall MySQL from my computer via Homebrew:

```
$ brew uninstall mysql --ignore-dependencies
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12... (255 files, 233.0MB)
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12
```

So instead, I removed and reinstalled MySQL manually:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/mysql
$ brew cleanup
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
$ brew install mysql
```

And that worked!

Comment: Warning - this method will remove all of your databases (in the /usr/local/var/mysql folder).

Answer (score 15):

Below I'm including the latest instructions from `brew install mysql` so newer searches for this issue can benefit:

```
$ brew install mysql
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mysql-5.6.26.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring mysql-5.6.26.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz

To connect:
    mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mysql now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  mysql.server start
```

In my case I loaded mysql now via `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` and was then able to launch `$ mysql` and be on my way.

Answer (score 12):

This problem related to `/usr/local/var/mysql` folder access, I remove this folder and reinstall mysql.

1. uninstall mysql with brew :

   `brew uninstall mysql`
2. `sudo rm -r /usr/local/var/mysql`
3. `brew install mysql@8.0`
4. `mysql -u root`

This solution works fine for me!
**BUT YOU LOST ALL YOUR DATABASES! WARNING!**

Comment: This will more than likely fix the problem, however to future readers, be warned that this will wipe out all your databases.  It's basically a hard re-install of MySQL.  I know the context of the question was a fresh install, but some people that are scanning may just try this without knowing of the damage it could cause on an existing/production install.

Comment: This isn't actually a solution. This is "Have you tried turning it on and off again?"

Answer (score 11):

In my case it was simply a matter of deleting a lock file.

```
sudo rm -f /tmp/mysql.sock.lock
```

Comment: I tired everything, several times installing, uninstalling, cleaning, purging, removing using brew in mac bigsur OS. Finally, this solution worked for me. Atleast I have moved further with and able to login in to MYSQL via terminal. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting I am having the error saying not being able to connect to socket in '/tmp/mysql.sock', however, my actual filename inside '/tmp' is 'mysql_3306.sock.lock'. I dont if port number being there is why mysql is throwing error.
But everytime I delete it restart mysql, it recreates the same file.

Answer (score 10):

This fixed my issue when I restarted the mysql service. Just run:

```
brew services start mysql
```

Answer (score 9):

Ough, that took me a while to figure out. I saw it in a comment. After installing mysql using brew, and starting the service (perhaps using `sudo brew services start mysql`) then run:

```
$ mysqld
```

And MySQL should be running for your thereafter.

Answer (score 7):

For me it was simple as running:

`/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`

instead of `mysqld`

Comment: This worked for me. Not sure why, but it may be related to a Mac OS restart bug on my machine

Comment: turns out I need to run this command every time I restart my machine. I'm happy I have something to get it up and running, but I wish there was something more persistent

Answer (score 4):

After working on this for several hours what worked for me was
go to /etc/mysql/  and edit the my.cnf file.  Add the following

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: This did the trick for me too, though for my os/mysql version it was: /etc/my.conf, and the socket was in /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

/var/log/mysqld.log should point you to where the socket file is.

Comment: Add skip_ssl in the same file if it doesn't work

Comment: This worked for me for rh7.9. only file path and socket path was different.                  file path : /etc/my.conf socket path :  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock which can be search using sudo find / -type s command

Answer (score 4):

I went through this issue and I managed to run mysql server using below solution

Install mysql through `.dmg`(https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html), you will get mysql service panel in system preferences then start mysql from the panel and try

`mysql -u root -p`

Images attached for reference

[image: System Preferences]

[image: Mysql panel]

Answer (score 4):

just hit "brew services start mysql" in terminal

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to my problem. It was indeed because my MySQL server was not running.

It was caused by MySQL not being correctly set up on my machine, thus not being able to run.

**To remedy this, I used a script which installs MySQL on Mac OSX Mountain Lion**, which must have installed missing files.

Here is the link: http://code.macminivault.com/

**Important Note:** *This script sets the root password as a randomly generated string, which it saves on the Desktop, so take care not to delete this file and to note the password. It also installs MySQL manager in your system preferences. I'm also not sure if removes any existing databases, so be careful about that.*

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to run

```
  mysql.server start
```

before going to

```
  mysql -u root -p
```

so as to make sure that the mysql server is running before trying to login into it

This happens many times what you start/restart a machine where by no mysql server  is running.

Answer (score 3):

AFTER USING ALL THE ABOVE SOLUTIONS, NOTHING WORKED FOR ME BUT THIS WORKED.

I you have installed MySQL using HomeBrew then check ***System Preferences > MySQL*** in your mac that MySQL Server is stopped if it is running stop it[image] by clicking on **Stop MySQL Server** and start MySQL from terminal writing the command  `mysqlserver.start`.

If it doesn't work you can also try:-

If you have also installed MySQL workbench then just uninstall **MySQL workbench and MySQL** and after that install **MySQL first and then MySQL workbench.**

Answer (score 3):

Probably you might have faced some issues during the homebrew mysql installation and mysql services might not be running. If that is the case, then it might be worth trying below steps to reinstall mysql properly and then try to connect.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Library/Caches/Homebrew

brew uninstall mysql

brew install mysql

mysql.server start   

mysql -uroot
```

Comment: Thanks! in my case, the second command is `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar`

Comment: My Case
1. my mysql can start with the command: `sudo   /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir\=/usr/local/var/mysql` , (yes, this command come from the installation of mysql with brew)
2. but the service command does not working. 
3. i check the `/usr/local/var/mysql/YourComputerName.err` log and find:  `2023-11-26T06:28:43.182701Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!` 
and finally fix it by:
1. brew services stop mysql@5.7
2. sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/mysql
3. brew services start mysql@5.7

Answer (score 2):

After trying many solutions, seems like the one that finally did the trick was to connect by IP. No longer file sockets getting deleted randomly.

Just update your MySQL client config (e.g. `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`) with:

```
[client]
port = 3306
host=127.0.0.1
protocol=tcp
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried every possible way to solve this issue, like ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock, uninstall and reinstall mysql, make sure mysql is running on xampp but none of it still worked.

Finally, I open up my.cnf (config file) and copy the socket path (make sure to copy the full path else it won't work). Then I perform this command in my terminal

```
mysql --socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Lo, and behold, mysql launchs.

This solution will only work if your MySQL is shown running on Xampp/Ampps, but in terminal it is still not connecting to the right socket when you have already attempted something like:

```
./mysql -u root
```

or

```
brew services start mysql
```

Comment: I also tried every suggested solution from this post, and it has not worked. Do you need xampp installed? i am not familiar with this. I only installed mysql server GPL version from official website (.DMG). I don't believe I have this app--XAMPP. Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: `brew services start mysql` is the one worked for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

only this has made the trick for me
`brew services start --all`
(after trying all answers)

Comment: Explain how is it related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I keep coming back to this post, I've encountered this error several times. It might have to do with importing all my databases after doing a fresh install.

I'm using homebrew. The only thing that used to fix it for me:

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This morning, the issue returned after my machine decided to shut down overnight. The only thing that fixed it now was to upgrade mysql.

```
brew upgrade mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue by changing localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Can you add some details to this, like what config file did you change? What was the previous value.  The phrase "changing localhost to 127.0.0.1" sounds like you are editing your `/etc/hosts` file and it should already be 127.0.0.1 .

Comment: On your command add ip address instead of localhost mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

Answer (score 1):

For my case, just specify host as 127.0.0.1, instead of localhost:

```
$ bin/mysql -uroot -p -h127.0.0.1
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.26

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Comment: I had same error as OP but not by using homebrew. I have installed MySQL through DBengin, on MacOS Monterey M1. So if someone is in the same situation, the solution for me was same as @Liu Yan: mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 specify the host

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew will absolutely never repair the permissions using a standard reinstall, and chasing down which folder/file is corrupted will take longer than it is worth.

In this case - blow away the mysql install manually and reinstall via homebrew. Takes about 2 minutes.

`cd /usr/local/var`

`sudo rm -rf mysql`

`brew install mysql`

Homebrew installs mysql insecure by default, so if you want a password:

`mysql_secure_installation`

Then fire it up.

`mysql -uroot`

Answer (score 1):

After installing **MySQL** on my **mac m1 macOS Monterey**, using `brew install mysql` I got this info:

```
[System] [MY-013169] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.27_1/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) initializing of server in progress as process 3624

[ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.

[ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.

[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

[System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.27_1/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27)  Homebrew.
```

and this warning:

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully You can
try again using:   brew postinstall mysql
```

After that I try to start MySQL using `brew services start mysql`, and I got this **error**:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I managed to fix it using:

```
> rm -rf ~/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/
> brew postinstall mysql
```

Now you can connect with `mysql -uroot` or `mysql -uroot -p`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Kali linux you might want to specify the host explicitly

do that with
`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root`
where 127.0.0.1 is your localhost

Answer (score 0):

None worked. I just reinstall mysql (don't worry your data is stay untouched).

then start using

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

That's all. brew services mysql start not starting mysql.

On MacOS Monterey.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It got a progress on my Mac. However, I still run into another error. like the following. ➜  ~ sudo mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
.Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/HHT-Notebook.local.err'.
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/HHT-Notebook.local.pid).

Answer (score -1):

In my case right after installing the MAMP accessing mysql from the terminal was giving the same socket error. At the end all it wanted was a restart and it's working.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of other helpful responses here, but nothing fixed this for me. Ultimately nothing I found on this site or others would get any version of MySQL from Homebrew working for me.

It was super painless to just download the DMG from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=479114 (find the appropriate version you need) and let the wizard install it for me. The only other manual step was adding `/usr/local/mysql/bin` to my PATH.

I'd recommend this option if brew is giving you trouble.

Update - if this still doesn't fix it, try completely purging mysql before installing via DMG. Follow these instructions: https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d

Comment: i installed via the DMG file too, but i still get this socket error. mysql --version works for me and --help, but nothing else. I added to path in order to get the --version and --help commands to work. can you please provide some advice? thanks.

Comment: See the update about purging mysql first. That's been fixing it for myself and several coworkers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql && brew postinstall mysql@5.7 && brew services restart mysql@5.7
```

Answer (score -1):

Encountered a similar problem after upgrading to Catalina OS. After running mysqld command, I found that there was some issue with the logs file. It could be different for others.

```
$ mysqld
```

Issue was

```
2019-10-16T04:58:59.174474Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: No such file or directory
2019-10-16T04:58:59.174508Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Resolved it by creating it and applying proper permissions.

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/mysql
sudo touch /var/log/mysql/error.log
sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/
```

Restart MySQL

```
brew services restart mysql@5.7
```

Issue was resolved.

```
mysql -uroot -proot
```

Answer (score -1):

Running `sudo chown _mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/*` helped me finally after trying multitude of options from all these SO answers. The issue with permissions probably arose from improper shutdown of the machine.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on OSX and have XAMPP,then please follow these steps:

Thanks to Jackstine's answer, I was able to do the following:

$ cat ~/.my.cnf

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I hope this helps me again when I forget, in the future!

Answer (score -1):

1)->First start the SQL server
2)(if not exists)you have to create an 'etc' dir at where you installed
mysql->in that create a file named 'mysql.sock'.
3)then execute the below line

```
 ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

4)restart the server

5)and find the path for 'mysql.sock' by executing below line

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -e "select @@socket"
```

now you can see the path ->copy that path
6)after copied execute the below line

```
mysql -u (username) -p -S (paste the path you copied)
```

7)Now ,it works.

Answer (score -4):

1. Uninstall MySQL.
2. Remove `/usr/local/var/mysql/`.
3. Install MySQL.

Comment: Will this not blow away all databases you may have? Seems like a rather heavy-handed solution to me, especially considering it's probably just a problem of MySQL not running.

Comment: yes it will , but as per the question , this was a fresh install and hence the assumption was that there would ot be any databases.