# Forgot MySQL password OSX -- Tutorials to reset not working

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed MySQL and forgot my root password (Mac OSX El Capitan).

I am using the tutorial by `[Ubuntu][1]` to reset my password but I am having issues very early

I type `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`

And get `sudo: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server: command not found`

I move forward anyway and type:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
mysql -u root
```

And I get

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

Any suggestions?
(NEVERMIND- FIGURED IT OUT, I POSTED ANSWER BELOW)

Comment: Ubuntu is not OS X. The instructions will be completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. Interestingly, a big part of this problem is the lack of knowledge and information. So I found this question [For a newbie: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450091/for-a-newbie-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-so) after searching for the  bottom error solution.

The solution said it may be installed but not running. Suggested typing `brew info mysql`

Turns out, I never set a root password.

And so, I started mysql so I could set a root password. I typed `brew services start mysql` (reqs homebrew)

Next:

```
$ mysql -u root
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE User='root';    mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit
```

Switch NEWPASSWORD with your new password (thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474890/4330767)

Should fix now.

Comment: I don't think there is a lack of information, just finding it in the sea of permutations