# Docker ports not being exposed properly

Tags: docker

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/redditaurus
    environment:
      - REDDIT_KEY=${REDDIT_KEY}
      - REDDIT_SECRET=${REDDIT_SECRET}
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    # volumes:
    #   - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql/
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

This is my docker-compose.yml. The weirdest thing is happening. I can visit localhost:8000 and get the redditaurus app without any issue. However, if I try to do the same thing with localhost:80, or localhost:3306 from a mysql terminal, I'll get access denied or ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

If I try 0.0.0.0:80, I get the default nginx page, so that's okay, but why won't localhost work?

MySQL refuses to be served on either localhost or 0.0.0.0. I've tried accessing it from Sequel Pro, from inside a linked container, and from my host machine's console, and nothing can get into it. If I exec into the SQL container, I can log in just fine, so it's not a password issue.

Why can't I get to my containers normally? :(

Comment: Try executing `lsof -i :3306` on your host machine and post the output. And check if mysql container running with `docker ps`

Comment: @SaqibAhmed thanks for your response.

I can confirm docker ps returns that all containers are running, supposedly on their proper ports. Why does lsof show 3307? I tried logging on that port, but it also failed.

Comment: Just as an experiment, remove `"` in ports argument. I never used quotes with port mapping.

Comment: `COMMAND    PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 3307 mansoor   18u  IPv4 0xd199c22d9e34617d      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
com.docke 3307 mansoor   24u  IPv6 0xd199c22d966b9df5      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)`

Comment: @SaqibAhmed i tried doing it without the ". It did not change anything.  I try to keep them as strings to avoid problems like https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/550

Comment: Did you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in SequelPro?

Answer (score 1):

You have missing some configuration properties. try this

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/redditaurus
    environment:
      - REDDIT_KEY=${REDDIT_KEY}
      - REDDIT_SECRET=${REDDIT_SECRET}
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    entrypoint: ['/entrypoint.sh', '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "YES"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

if you want to connect mysql via terminal. run this
`mysql -uroot -proot —protocol tcp`

Next thing is your nginx binding with 80 is work correct.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Problem in here is not docker-compose. It can be in your os configurations.

Comment: This did not work.
The entry point script is built into the default mysql Docker image. It doesn't need to be added.

Running httpd with inplace of nginx runs fine on localhost, as does the python-tornado applicaiton.

Comment: This is not error in docker-compose. You can see all the success   messages here. It works correct in my machine

Comment: it's the generic mysql error. `root@3640d1327a5a:/# mysql 192.168.10.192 -u root -proot
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: try this. 
mysql -uroot -proot —protocol tcp not this mysql 192.168.10.192 -u root -proot

Comment: run  mysql -uroot -proot —protocol tcp and put the response plz

Comment: ```mysql -uroot -proot -protocol tcp
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)```

Comment: ```CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
bb194ff9719a        redditaurus_app     "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   2 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   redditaurus_app_1
618e05d9141e        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   redditaurus_mysql_1```

Comment: I think you're right in saying that it's my OS configuration, but I have no idea what it could be. It's just OSX running Docker. I haven't done any sort of customization to the config.

Comment: is there any local mysql instance run in your machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450091/for-a-newbie-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-so?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: mysql -h localhost -uroot -proot -protocol tcp

Answer (score 1):

I used mysql:5.7 tag in docker-compose, and that allowed the container to work. I guess the latest branch has some issue with my local env.

Still not sure what's up with nginx, but it's not an issue.