# mysql.server start wont start the mysql server

Tags: mysql, macos

Whenever I type "mysql.server start" on OSX terminal I get this error:

Maria-MacBook-Pro:~ mariakocsis$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
./usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/mysqld_safe: line 647: /var/lib/mysql/Maria-MacBook-Pro.local.err: No such file or directory
Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/Maria-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
2018-05-31T12:12:39.6NZ mysqld_safe Directory '/var/lib/mysql' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /var/lib/mysql/Maria-MacBook-Pro.local.err: No such file or directory
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/Maria-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).
Maria-MacBook-Pro:~ mariakocsis$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql/
chmod: /usr/local/mysql/: No such file or directory
Maria-MacBook-Pro:~ mariakocsis$

Even if I try to run mysql by MAMP, its not working.

Before the error I followed this commands:
cd ; nano .bash_profile

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -v

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/mysqld_safe ; exit;

source ~/.bash_profile mysql -v

in your terminal type in: mysql

source ~/.bash_profile mysql -v

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';

sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7

sudo nano /etc/my.cnf

How can I reset this things?
And how I can start mysql server?

Comment: How did you install mysql?

Comment: simple brew install mysql

Comment: Try this `sudo /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`

Comment: I got this...: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Answer (score 0):

Use command below:
To start mysql: mysqld start
To stop mysql: mysqld stop
To restart: mysqld restart

Comment: I got this...:mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2018-05-31T12:48:21.913827Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-05-31T12:48:21.914004Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to

Comment: NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2018-05-31T12:48:21.914044Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.22) starting as process 5277 ...
2018-05-31T12:48:21.916481Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Maria-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
2018-05-31T12:48:21.916504Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Maria-MacBook-Pro.lower-test
2018-05-31T12:48:21.916581Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to /var/lib/mysql/
2018-05-31T12:48:21.916587Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: 2018-05-31T12:48:21.916594Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-05-31T12:48:21.916645Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: for mysqld start

Comment: what do u get it u type mysql -u root -p

Comment: Maria-MacBook-Pro:~ mariakocsis$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Maria-MacBook-Pro:~ mariakocsis$

Comment: use mysql.server start for starting      and check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450091/for-a-newbie-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-so