# error 2002 (hy000) while install mysql - Poweredge

Tags: mysql

Hi guys please can you help

I tried to uninstall everything and reinstall its the same error.

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-08-06 01:57:43 +04; 15s ago
    Process: 17594 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, s>
   Main PID: 17602 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 38 (limit: 250426)
     Memory: 365.2M
        CPU: 730ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─17602 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Aug 06 01:57:42 beast systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 06 01:57:43 beast systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
lines 1-14/14 (END)
[1]+  Stopped                 service mysql status
set mark: 
root@beast:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
root@beast:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
root@beast:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
root@beast:~# sudo mysql_secure_installation
mysql_secure_installation: [ERROR] unknown option '--no-auto-rehash'.

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

format.
uninstall everything
install back
[Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436028/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock-2)
[ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450091/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mys)
done some googling and youtube

```
root@beast:~# brew services start mysql
Command 'brew' not found, did you mean:
  command 'qbrew' from deb qbrew (0.4.1-8build1)
  command 'brec' from deb bplay (0.991-10build1)
Try: apt install <deb name>
root@beast:~# sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql && sudo brew services restart mysql@5.7
chown: invalid user: ‘_mysql:mysql’
root@beast:~# sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
chown: invalid user: ‘_mysql:mysql’
root@beast:~# mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
root@beast:~# sudo mysql.server start
sudo: mysql.server: command not found
root@beast:~# brew info mysql
Command 'brew' not found, did you mean:
  command 'qbrew' from deb qbrew (0.4.1-8build1)
  command 'brec' from deb bplay (0.991-10build1)
Try: apt install <deb name>
root@beast:~# mysql -u root -p h127.0.0.1
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
root@beast:~# mysql -u root -p hlocalhost
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
root@beast:~#
```

Please help I am still learning