# Can't Fix Mariadb & Mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) On MacOs

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Recently I Found This Error For log in to my mysql and mariadb on My UnixBase MacOS. And i try similar Ways in StackOverFlow To fix this problem. but problem not solved.

[image: Terminal Error]

i try systemctl to check mariadb or mysql is running.

[image]

But it seems systemctl command is not available on macOS system.

Then i try to look at mariadb version.

[image]

i use this [StackOverFlowLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450091/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mys). But Nothing Changes

Actually i use my mariadb server for about one year on my MacOS, And I dont know why this trouble happened recently.

Comment: You can check if mysql is running with the following command: `mysqladmin -u root -p status`

Answer (score 2):

`systemctl` is systemd, which is Linux only.

`brew services start mariadb` is for MacOS.

[ref](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-on-macos-using-homebrew/)